# How to use Intel Pin on MPI code

Tags: mpi, instrumentation, intel-pin

I am pretty new to MPI and Intel Pin. I already installed pin-2.13-62732-gcc.4.4.7-linux on my linux environment, I need t use this tool on MPI codes. foreexample I want to get the number of instruction(such as inscount0 which is already existed in pin) of MPI code (like imul.c). Would you tell me what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

The least painful way I found is to use tau_pin. https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/docs/old/re39.html

Answer (score 0):

You can start analysis of your MPI application following way:

```
mpirun –np $NPROCS pin -t $PIN_TOOL -- $APP
```

It the same as in case of Valgrind: [Using valgrind to spot error in mpi code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851643/using-valgrind-to-spot-error-in-mpi-code)