# Using valgrind to spot error in mpi code

Tags: mpi, valgrind

I have a code which works perfect in serial but with `mpirun -n 2 ./out` it gives the following error:

```
./out': malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x00000000024aa090
```

I tried to use valgrind such as:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes mpirun -n 2 ./out
```

I got the following output:

```
==3494== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3494== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3494== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3494== Command: mpirun -n 2 ./out
==3494== 
Grid_0/NACA0012.msh
Grid_0/NACA0012.msh
>>> Number of cells: 7734
>>> Number of cells: 7734
0.000000  0         1.470622e-02
*** Error in `./out': malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x00000000024aa090 ***

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 3497 RUNNING AT orhan
=   EXIT CODE: 134
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Aborted (signal 6)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
==3494== 
==3494== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3494==     in use at exit: 131,120 bytes in 2 blocks
==3494==   total heap usage: 1,064 allocs, 1,062 frees, 231,859 bytes allocated
==3494== 
==3494== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3494==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3494==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3494==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3494==    still reachable: 131,120 bytes in 2 blocks
==3494==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3494== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==3494== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==3494== 
==3494== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3494== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I am not good in valgrind but what I understood is valgrind saw no problem. Are there better options for valgrind to spot the source of the specific error mentioned?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Note that with the invocation above,

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes mpirun -n 2 ./out
```

you are running valgrind on the program `mpirun`, which presumably has been extensively tested and works correctly, and not the program `./out`, which you know to have a problem.

To run valgrind on your test program you will want to do:

```
mpirun -n 2 valgrind --leak-check=yes ./out
```

Which uses mpirun to launch 2 processes, each running `valgrind --leak-check=yes ./out`.

Comment: As a side note, running valgrind on an mpi program will often generate lots of false positives to fish through; it's always worth trying running it through valgrind as a serial program, as well.  The serial program doesn't actually cause a crashing error, but the erroneous memory accesses that cause the error may still be occurring, but with less drastic consequences.

Comment: Also worth noting is this page from valgrind on running with mpi: https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mpiwrap

Answer (score 29):

You can never go wrong with a Jonathan Dursi answer but let me just add that with more than one processor it can be a pain to read valgrind output.

Instead of outputting to the console, dump it to a log file.  Of course if you dump both processes to the same log file that's not going to be helpful.  Instead, log to multiple files -- valgrind interprets '%p' as the process id so you get two (or more) log files:

```
mpiexec -np 2 valgrind --leak-check=full \
    --show-reachable=yes --log-file=nc.vg.%p ./noncontig_coll2 -fname blah
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also choose to run valgrind on the outside, but have it track all the forks using `--trace-children=yes`. I do this because it is less typing.

Comment: That approach only works with mpirun and on a single node.