# Why does MPI_Init (NULL, NULL) cause memory leakage?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mpi, valgrind

`MPI_Init(NULL, NULL)` and `MPI_Finalize()` are required for an MPI project. However, I do not know why I got the `definitely lost` for `MPI_Init(NULL, NULL)` when I used Valgrind to check memory leakage. I got the following error multiple times: (My program runs well)

```
==27956== 74 (64 direct, 10 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 258 of 433
==27956==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==27956==    by 0x9538757: ???
==27956==    by 0x90F550B: ???
==27956==    by 0x90D8942: ???
==27956==    by 0x90A7F3D: ???
==27954==    by 0x50DFFF1: ompi_mpi_init (in /opt/lib/libmpi.so.40.10.2)
==27954==    by 0x510CC58: PMPI_Init (in /opt/lib/libmpi.so.40.10.2)
==27954==    by 0x4039D4: main (ssvm_main.cpp:17)
```

By the way, ```` MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD)``` also has error with ```uninitialised value(s) ````.

How can I fix them?

Comment: these are warnings you can safely ignore. Open MPI should provide a `valgrind` config file that should get rid of the `uninitialized values` warnings (but once again, those caused by Open MPI can be safely ignored).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851643/using-valgrind-to-spot-error-in-mpi-code ?

Comment: @dreamcrash I don't think so. Here is a warning, there is a corruption causing a crash. There are some good insights in the answers and comments though.

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @TimBoddy Yes! But actually the errors happen once I use `MPI_Init(NULL, NULL)`. The code I used is just a simple example.
`
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    printf("Hello world from rank %d out of %d processors\n", world_rank, world_size);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
`

Comment: My guess is that you can debug this as follows.  Run your simple program under gdb, without valgrind, and set a breakpoint for that **return 0** line.  When you get there create a core dump.  Then clone and build https://github.com/vmware/chap and start chap on your core file.  A command to run from the chap prompt in such a case is show unreferenced /extend ~> /commentExtensions true /redirectSuffix leakInfo