# Results of parallel calculations on Fortran + mpi are dependent on being/luck of unsignificant commands in code

Tags: multiprocessing, fortran, mpi

Good day to everyone!

I perform parallel calculations using `Fortran` + `mpi` (technical details on compilator, OS are listed in the end of this question) and I have the following problem: the result of calculations is changed dramatically if I add or remove a line in my code, that is absolutely irrelevant for very calculations.

The whole code consists of three parts:

1. the main program `IntColl.f90` containing parallel fragments of the code
2. module `m.f90` containing lots of functions to perform specific calculations. One of functions in this module contains the lines being or lack of which in the code is reflected on results of calculations.
3. module `Constants.f90` containing various constants.

The code contains about 2k lines so I only can to show some fragments, which in my opinion have the most significant mean to the question.

Here are code snippets from the main program file `IntColl.f90` with parallel calculations:

```
    DO counter1 = 1, NG
        IF ( MOD ( counter1, CN ) .EQ. RANK ) THEN
            YDOT ( counter1      ) = FACTOR  * ABt  ( dmgw ( counter1 ) ) + &
                                     FACTOR1 * CIng ( dmgw ( counter1 ) )
            YDOT ( counter1 + NG ) = FACTOR  * ABMt ( dmgw ( counter1 ) )
        END IF
    END DO

    DO counter = 1, ( CN - 1 )
        IF ( RANK .EQ. counter ) THEN
            CALL MPI_SEND (       &
                YDOT ( counter ), &
                1,                &
                MPI_DP_VEC,       &
                0,                &
                1,                &
                MPI_COMM_WORLD,   &
                IERROR            &
                          )
        END IF
        IF ( RANK .EQ. 0 ) THEN
            CALL MPI_RECV (        &
                YDOT ( counter ),  &
                1,                 &
                MPI_DP_VEC,        &
                counter,           &
                1,                 &
                MPI_COMM_WORLD,    &
                MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, &
                IERROR             &
                          )
        END IF
    END DO

    CALL MPI_BCAST (          &
        YDOT      ( 1    ),   &
        2 * NG,               &
        MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
        RANK,                 &
        MPI_COMM_WORLD,       &
        IERROR                &
                   )
```

`CN` is the number of threads.

Next, here is the function `CIng ( p )` from module `m.f90` called within parallel piece of the code:

```
REAL ( DP ) FUNCTION CIng ( p )     ! Collisional integral for \nu + \gamma
IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER :: i, CTR

    REAL ( DP ) :: p       ! p is coordinate momentum of initial neutrino: nu ( p ) + gamma ( k ) --> nu ( q ) + e^- ( q1 ) + e^+ ( q2 )
    REAL ( DP ) :: const_A
    REAL ( DP ) :: const_i
    REAL ( DP ) :: const
    REAL ( DP ) :: a, b

    REAL ( DP ) :: z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7

    i   = 0
    CTR = 0

    const_A = 128.D+00 * PI * FSC * G_F ** 2 * ( M_E / X ) ** 2
    const_i = ( DSQRT ( YMAX ** 2 + X ** 2 ) - X ) ** 2 * YMAX / 2.D+00 ** 8 / PI ** 5 / p * ( M_E / X ) ** 3
    const = const_A * const_i

    a = 0.D+00

    z1 = 0.D+00
    z2 = 0.D+00
    z3 = 0.D+00
    z4 = 0.D+00
    z5 = 0.D+00
    z6 = 0.D+00
    z7 = 0.D+00

    DO i = 1, NS
        b = 0.D+00
        z1 = x1 ( i )
        z2 = x2 ( i )
        z3 = x3 ( i )
        z4 = x4 ( i )
        z5 = x5 ( i )
        z6 = x6 ( i )
        z7 = x7 ( i )
        b = UndInt ( p, z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7 )
        a = a + b
        IF ( b .NE. 0.D+00 ) THEN
            CTR = CTR + 1
            WRITE ( 9, "(2ES23.15)" ) x2 ( i ), x3 ( i ) ! This #1
        END IF
    END DO

    print *, p, CTR, 'q'                                 ! This #2

    CIng = const * a / NS

END FUNCTION CIng
```

The thing is when I comment lines marked with labels `This #1` and `This #2` the result of calculations I obtain differs catastrophically from the results obtained when these lines are not commented. Note: results of calculations obtained are "good" in my opinion if at least one of these two lines are not commented.

Some clarification: the result of my calculations is some physical dependence which should be at least piecewise smooth. I really obtain points which lie on a piecewise smooth curve at some conditions (third level of optimization at compilation and not commented line `This #1`), and such result I guess "good". When I comment I/O instructions points become similar to noise without any visual dependence. And I consider intuitively such the result "bad".

The function `CIng ( p )` calls one more function `UndInt ( p, z1, z2, z3, z4, z5 ,z6, z7 )` which in turn calls next functions, but all these functions just perform some calculations.
Arrays `x1 ( i )`, `x2 ( i )`, ... are filled with numbers from a file in `IntColl.f90`. These arrays are declared in the module `Constants.f90` and this module are used in the main program `IntColl.f90` and in the module `m.f90`.

I have to say that the result of calculations is also dependent on level 'n' of optimization at compilation (`-O<n>`). When both lines `#This 1` and `#This 2` are commented results of calculations are bad at any level of optimization.

I tried to add options `-Wall` and `-Wextra` when compiling. These options showed lots of warnings of following types:
`<variable> may be uninitialized in this function`
and
`Inequality comparison for REAL(8) at (1)`.

Adding of options `-fbacktrace -fcheck=all -g` when compiling lead to "bad" result even if one of lines `This #1` and `This #2` are not commented.

The major part of these warnings are related to functions from fortran libraries I use in my program (e.g., DLSODA).

I also want to specify that time of calculation of value `CIng ( dmgw ( counter1 ) )` grows monotonously when `counter1` goes from 1 to `NG` (`NG` is 96 if it matters).

Here are a few technical details:
The code is written on Fortran90, I compile it using the command
`mpif90.mpich *.f90 *.f -O3 -o <name>`
and I execute it using the command
`mpirun -np <number of threads> ./<name>`,
in terminal of my computer with the OS Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS, version of `mpirun` is 3.3a2;
on the version of compiler: `mpif90 --version` reports `GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`.

Please, say me if it is needed any additional information.
I will be grateful for any answer/comment on this qestion or for information about same problems known earlier.

UPD

I am very ashamed, but it has been found out that my problem is absolutely not related with multiprocessing.
The thing is I had in program a variable that could stay uninitialized when program is executed.

Namely, in module `m.f90` I have a function `UndInt_ ( ... )` containing internal variables `a` and `b`.
If these variables are not initialized immediately after their declaration their initialization is performed within a chain of quite intricate nested IF conditions:

```
REAL ( DP ) FUNCTION UndInt_ ( p, k, eps1, eps2, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 )
IMPLICIT NONE

    REAL ( DP ), INTENT ( IN ) :: p, k, eps1, eps2, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2

    REAL ( DP ) :: q1     ! q1   is the coordinate momentum of electron ( the momentum of electron multiplied by ( X / M_E ) )
    REAL ( DP ) :: q2     ! q2   is the coordinate momentum of positron
    REAL ( DP ) :: sinTh1
    REAL ( DP ) :: sinTh2
    REAL ( DP ) :: cosph1
    REAL ( DP ) :: cosph2

    REAL ( DP ) :: cosThk ! cos of the polar angle                    of electron
    REAL ( DP ) :: q      ! the absolute value of coordinate momentum of outgoing neutrino

    REAL ( DP ) :: a, b

    a = 0.0 ! This variable
    b = 0.0 ! And this variable

    q1     = DSQRT ( eps1 ** 2 - X ** 2 ) 
    q2     = DSQRT ( eps2 ** 2 - X ** 2 )
    sinTh1 = DSQRT ( 1.D+00 - cosTh1 ** 2 )
    sinTh2 = DSQRT ( 1.D+00 - cosTh2 ** 2 )
    cosph1 = DCOS  ( phi1 )
    cosph2 = DCOS  ( phi2 )

     IF ( ( k ** 2 * ( q1 * cosTh1          + q2 * cosTh2          - p ) ** 2      + &
            k ** 2 * ( q1 * sinTh1 * cosph1 + q2 * sinTh2 * cosph2     ) ** 2        &
          ) .LT.                                                                     &
          ( p * ( k - eps1 - eps2 ) - k * ( eps1 + eps2 ) + eps1 * eps2 + X ** 2   + &
            p * q1 * cosTh1 + p * q2 * cosTh2                                      - &
            q1 * q2 * ( sinTh1 * sinTh2 * DCOS ( phi1 - phi2 ) + cosTh1 * cosTh2 )   &
          ) ** 2                                                                     &
        ) THEN
         a = 0.0
         b = 0.0
     ELSE
         IF (   ( cosThk1 ( p, k, eps1, eps2, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 ) .GT.  1.D+00 ) &
           .OR. ( cosThk1 ( p, k, eps1, eps2, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 ) .LT. -1.D+00 ) &
          .AND. ( cosThk2 ( p, k, eps1, eps2, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 ) .GT.  1.D+00 ) &
           .OR. ( cosThk2 ( p, k, eps1, eps2, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 ) .LT. -1.D+00 ) &
            ) THEN
             a = 0.0
             b = 0.0
         ELSE
             IF ( ( DABS ( p + k - eps1 - eps2                                          - &
                     q_1 ( p, k, eps1, eps2, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 )                 &
                         )                                                              / &
                         ( p + k - eps1 - eps2 )                                          &
                  ) .LT. 1.D-015                                                          &
                ) THEN
                cosThk = cosThk1 ( p, k,    eps1, eps2,         cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 )
                q      =     q_1 ( p, k,    eps1, eps2,         cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 )
                a      = UndInt1 ( p, k, q, eps1, eps2, cosThk, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 )
             END IF
             IF ( ( DABS ( p + k - eps1 - eps2                                          - & 
                     q_2 ( p, k, eps1, eps2, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 )                 &
                         )                                                              / &
                         ( p + k - eps1 - eps2 )                                          &
                  ) .LT. 1.D-015 .AND.                                                    &
                  ( DABS (                                                                &
               ( cosThk1 ( p, k, eps1, eps2, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 )               - &
                 cosThk2 ( p, k, eps1, eps2, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 ) )             / &
                 cosThk1 ( p, k, eps1, eps2, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 )                 &
                         )                                                                &
                  ) .GT. 1.D-015                                                           &
                ) THEN
                cosThk = cosThk2 ( p, k,    eps1, eps2,         cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 )
                q      =     q_2 ( p, k,    eps1, eps2,         cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 )
                b      = UndInt1 ( p, k, q, eps1, eps2, cosThk, cosTh1, cosTh2, phi1, phi2 )
            END IF
        END IF
    END IF

    UndInt_ = a + b

END FUNCTION UndInt_
```

It looks like for some cases these variables has been stayed uninitialized within the function `UndInt_` and were "dirty".

Finally a value of variable `UndInt_` that is returned by finction `UndInt_ ( ... )` is defined with variables `a` and `b`, so a junk from these variables has been passed to variable `UndInt_`.

That's it.

I understand, that this bug could be fixed immediately if I used options `-fbacktrace -fcheck=all -g` at compilation.

I would like to say thank you one more time for answers and comments.
I am going to be more careful in future.

Comment: To get some ideas about possible bugs in MPI code you might want to run it under valgrind (see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34858425/1328439))

Comment: I cannot quite understand the `DO counter=1, (CN-1)` loop. Do you really need to run a loop here on ranks other than 0? It seems that each rank except 0 executes exactly one `mpi_send()` call in this loop.

Comment: The lines you commented are console I/O routines. They might cause implicit synchronization or otherwise affect parallel program flow, so if your result depends on the order of operations, e.g. due to one process overwriting the results of another, this might cause difference in the final results.

Comment: Here is a link to a more detailed paper from HLRS on [using valgrind to check memory access bugs in MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/papers/parco-2007/parco-2007.pdf). The authors use Open-MPI, but that should be portable to MPICH.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov very interesting question, thank you! I try to understand how to pass ```YDOT ( counter )``` to RANK 0 without this loop. You are absolutely right that each rank except 0 executes exactly one ```mpi_send (  )``` in this loop

Comment: You haven't told us the name of the compiler - what does `mpif90 --version` report - *please* edit the question to include this, don't add it in a comment.

Comment: Also, assuming gfortran is the compiler, you have compiled and linked with `-fbacktrace -fcheck=all -g` and then run the code and see what happens? If you don't know what these flags do look them up - you really should use them the whole time when developing code.

Comment: @IanBush Thank you! Added this information to the body of my question.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov I had this thought that I have deal with implicit synchronization. I tried to use explicit synchronization using MPI_BARRIER, but it did not help.

Comment: @IanBush I didn't try ```-fbacktrace -fcheck=all -g```, thank you for the advice!

Comment: When developing **Always** use `-fbacktrace -fcheck=all -g`. From day -1.

Comment: @IanBush are these options when compiling?

Comment: Yes. And for simplicity include them when linking as well. You will find them described and strongly recommended many, many times in answers and comments here. You will also find many close to duplicates to your question, but I haven't got any time to search one out now.

Comment: @IanBush I'm very sorry, but what is linking?

Comment: If you use `mpif.h`, use `use mpi` instead. Most likely, something is called with incorrect arguments somewhere. If it does not help, check the types of all of your arguments. Pay attention to stuff like the `status` being an array and similar.

Comment: @IanBush I have tested compilation with options ```-fbacktrace -fcheck=all -g``` and these flags "worsen" results of my calculations

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Thank you for your comment! I use ```use mpi```. I will check options you said

Comment: What do you mean by "worsen"? Do you mean error messages? If so add those to the question

Comment: OK, it hasn't worsened, it's stayed the same, you have a bug but you haven't found it, you have just ruled out some of the most common reasons for what you are seeing. Other possible reasons you now need to check are argument mismatch (if you haven't got all your routines in modules), and misuse of any library you are using, such as mpi, blas or lapack. vlagrind is the most likely way you will find this. I'm also ignoring race conditions from what you show, but as what we see is not enough to diagnose the problem let alone debug it they can't be ruled out.

Comment: @IanBush I'm going to add to question definitions of "good" and "bad" result. The thing is the result of my calculations is some physical dependence which should be at least piecewise smooth. I really obtain points which lie on a piecewise smooth curve at some conditions (third level of optimization at compilation and not commented line ```This #1```), and such result I guess "good". When I comment I/O instructions points become similar to noise without any visual dependence. And I consider intuitively such the result "bad"

Comment: @IanBush so I say some actions "worsen" result if before these actions a could get "good" dependence of points calculated and after these actions a get "bad" dependence of points

Comment: Yes. I understand this entirely. I have seen it many times myself. The reason is you have a bug in your code. Until you fix this bug you will never know before you run it whether you will get "good" or "bad" results, or worse whether your "good" results really are "good". The most likely cause for finding the bug is writing to memory you shouldn't write to. `-fcheck=all` is the easiest attempt to try and diagnose this. Valgrind is the next thing to try. Anyway voting to close as there is insufficient detail to say more - we need a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: @IanBush I understand it, thank you. I'm going to try out advices I've got and I'll report on solution of my problem when it's solved

Comment: `<variable> may be uninitialized in this function` this should be a red flat: your code very likely exhibits an undefined behavior. Silence all these warnings first, and see how it goes.

Comment: When developing, use `-O0` to prevent aggressive options from the compiler to introduce some bugs/undefined behavior.